# how do I resolve "fatal error: linux/wakelock.h: No such file or directory" on Ubuntu?

Tags: android, ubuntu, linux-device-driver

I need linux/wakelock.h for building my code. I'm building this for x86_64

This is the kernel version I have - # uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-30-generic #44~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 23 18:32:41 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I even ran " sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)" to make sure I get the latest headers, but I'm still missing wakelock.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. wakelock.h is a an android file, it doesn't exist on Ubuntu. You will need the android headers if you need this file.